# PostgreSQL: get rows based on a date, between 2 date columns.

Tags: postgresql

I have the folowing table:

```
| id | duty_id |      date_start     |      date_end       |
| 1  |    1    | 2015-07-16 07:00:00 | 2015-07-16 14:30:00 |
| 2  |    3    | 2015-07-17 03:30:00 | 2015-07-17 11:00:00 |
| 3  |    5    | 2015-07-17 12:00:00 | 2015-07-17 19:30:00 |
```

and i have a date: `2015-07-17`.

and i need to select the rows that happens on my date. AKA i need these lines:

```
| 2  |    3    | 2015-07-17 03:30:00 | 2015-07-17 11:00:00 |
| 3  |    5    | 2015-07-17 12:00:00 | 2015-07-17 19:30:00 |
```

sadly the `BETWEEN` doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ('2015-07-17'::DATE BETWEEN date_start AND date_end)
```

gives back empty result.

How can i get those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE '2015-07-17'::DATE BETWEEN date_start::DATE AND date_end::DATE;
```

[SQLFiddle excample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/98b1a/6/0)

Comment: How? Did U see the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/98b1a/6/0) example? The query return 2 rows. The query from second answer gives back one row. Check please again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when a DATE is coerced to a TIMESTAMP (as must be done here to compare the DATE of '2015-07-17' to the TIMESTAMPs in the data) the time portion of the coerced TIMESTAMP is set to 00:00:00, and thus since the test data doesn't have a time period which is valid at midnight on 2015-07-17 no rows are returned.

If you add an INTERVAL literal of 211 minutes (three hours and 31 minutes) to the converted date you'll get results returned because the test data DOES have a row which is valid at 2015-07-17 at 03:31 AM:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
  WHERE '2015-07-17'::DATE + INTERVAL '211' MINUTE BETWEEN date_start
                                                       AND date_end;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e13c5/3)

Best of luck.